# MySQL: Change type from TIME to DATETIME and obtain the stored time

Tags: mysql, datetime, time

I have to change the type TIME to DATETIME, but I would like to receive the already stored times. When i simple change the type, i lost all stored times.

Is there a way to convert the TIME field to set the date to 0000-00-00 and to keep the time?

Thanks
Mirko

Comment: Why the need to convert to datetime yet store a date of 0000-00-00? Like why convert the field from TIME at all?

Comment: sorry I misread the mysql tag

Answer (score 0):

When altering the table you could put the default time to 0000-00-00

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue. How did you go about making the change to datetime?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74eb8/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`tm` time)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`tm`)
VALUES
    ('12:34:56')
;

alter table Table1
modify column `tm` datetime
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
*
from Table1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74eb8/1/0)**:

```
|                        tm |
|---------------------------|
| January, 04 2016 12:34:56 |
```

Comment: why i get in your SQL Fiddle the result of January, 01 1970 12:34:56 when i uncomment the last line (modify...), I would get only displays the time, sorry i can not reproduce your code, thanks

Comment: Please provide the steps you are using to alter the column, and also your version of mysql.

Comment: i use MySQL 5.5.42 and i use SequelPro to execute the commands. I have your code run step by step, but without the desired result

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue at sqlfidfle using mysql 5.5 and i dont have access to sequelpro. Sorry.